# How to bind a combobox inside wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

How to bind (Itemssource and selected item) of a combobox inside wpf datagrid? I am using MVVM pattern.
I have tried

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Example 9">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PartIds, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding PartId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCars}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Registration" Binding="{Binding Registration}"/>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Example 12">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarParts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" DisplayMemberPath="PartName" SelectedValuePath="PartID"  SelectedValue="{Binding PartId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding PartId}"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Properties used for data-binding

```
#region DataGrid List<String> Example

        public ObservableCollection<MyCar> MyCars { get; set; }
        public List<string> PartIds { get; set; } 

        #endregion

        #region DataGrid List<Class> Example

        public List<CarPart> CarParts { get; set; }

        #endregion
```

Reference:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Best-ComboBox-Tutorial-5cc27f82

Comment: How are you setting the DataContext of the Window control?

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = vm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }                                                                   }

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/combobox-in-datagrid-in-wpf/   this can help

Answer (score 6):

I've tried so many options but the easiest option i found is to generate load event of that combo box & Bind it with the list or data table.

e.g.
 In Xaml

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
                  <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPayee" Loaded="cmbPayee_Loaded" Text="{Binding PayeeName, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue ="{Binding PayeeID, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DisplayMemberPath = "Payee1" SelectedValuePath="PayeeID"/>
      </DataTemplate>
```

In .cs code

```
private void cmbPayee_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
            var res = from k in db.Payees
                      select k;
            cmb.ItemsSource = res.ToList();
            cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Payee1";
            cmb.SelectedValuePath = "PayeeID";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making your Lists observable collections.  You need to make sure your properties are telling your UI when new objects are added to your collection and that is what an `ObservableCollection` does for you.

Also make sure your `CarPart` and `MyCar` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Whether or not this is your problem depends on when exactly your properties are set.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess since I am not at my dev station, but try using ElementName to reference the window by name instead of relative source...

Something like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding CarParts,ElementName=MyWindowName}"
```

and the add a Name="MyWindowName" to the window definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this os .cs side

DataContext = CarParts;